# Jumping over a while-loop in Visual Studio debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Here is the scenario:
I put a breakpoint at the beginning of a method that I want to debug...

- First, lets say I want to debug (step through) the first part of the code.
- Then, there is a while-loop which I’m not interested in debugging (so let’s skip to the code after the while-loop).

Is it possible to **skip to the code after the while-loop** with the debugging options?

I want to do something like this:

```
BreakPoint: MyMethod()
{
    # First part of the code: Yes, I want to debug it.

    # while-loop: No, I do not want to debug it.

    # Second part of the code: Yes, I want to debug it too.
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Right-click on the line of code you want to run to, and click "Run To Cursor", or you can set a second breakpoint after the loop and just run.

**Edit:** You kind of asked two questions here. The method above will let you step over the whole loop, regardless of how many iterations it goes through. If you want to only go through the loop body 10 times, add a breakpoint on the last statement of the loop, right-click that line, click "Breakpoint", then "Hit count", then "break when hit count is equal to" and put 10 in the box that appears. This will pause the program after the loop executes 10 times (you will manually have to reposition the current statement), but will NOT break if the loop executes less than 10 times (add an additional breakpoint after the loop as I suggested above).

Comment: sorry for confusion, by 10 times I just meant lets say the loop is running 10 times and I do not want to hit the step into/over,etc ... button at least 10 times to just pass this loop.

Comment: Shortcut for "Run To Cursor": Ctrl-F10.

Answer (score 3):

You can put breakpoints before and after the `while` loop.

At the point before, press `F5` to "continue" on to the next breakpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly (as in, execute a loop 10 times), but you might be able to get something **very** close to your desired behavior.  Look into these MSDN links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepperboundaryattribute.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just put a breakpoint  on Part Two.  After you finish debugging part 1, hit run/f-5, and VS will run to the next breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Add a break point after the loop and let it continue into that break point.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't believe you can do what you are describing, your only options are those described by the other posters, it would be cool though :(

Answer (score 1):

[C# Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28VS.71%29.aspx)

```
BreakPoint : MyMethod
{
Part One of the code : Ok, lets debug it

#if !DEBUG
While Loop : I do not care, Do not want to debug it
#endif

Part Two of the code: Yes, I want to debug it too 
}
```

Comment: That simply omits the code at debugging time, I do not think that's what the OP wants.